# Cómo hacer una lista volviendo los números str

Tags: lista, bucles

Como crear una lista tipo: Lista_1=["El numero impar 1 es 21", "el numero impar 2 es 23",.....,"el numero impar n es 99"] si ya tengo la lista de numeros impares pero no sé cómo volverlos tipo str con el enunciado "El numero impar 1 es.."

```
List= [x for x in range(1,101)]
impar= []

for x in List:
    if  x>20:
        if  x%2!=0:
            impar.append(x)
           
print("Los numeros impares son: ")
print(impar)

Lista_1=["El numero impar "+str(x)+ " es "+str(j)+", "]
for x,j in enumerate(impar):
    str(x)
    L.append(str(j))
print(Lista_1)
```

El enunciado "el numero impar" sólo aparece una vez: ["El numero impar" 1 "es" 21, "23","25",...,"99"], no cada vez que imprimo un número ["El numero impar 1 es 21", "el numero impar 2 es 23",.....,"el numero impar n es 99"].

Comment: Por favor, edita tu pregunta, elimina las imágenes y pega el código en formato texto, de otra forma será difícil obtener respuestas.

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacer funcionar tu codigo introduciendo el append del string dentro de una variable llamada Lista_Textos todo esto ejecutando cuando iteras dentro del for.
quedaria mas o menos asi:

```
List= [x for x in range(1,101)]
impar= []

for x in List:
    if  x>20:
        if  x%2!=0:
            impar.append(x)
           
print("Los numeros impares son: ")
print(impar)

Lista_Textos = [];

for x,j in enumerate(impar):
    Lista_Textos.append(["El numero impar "+str(x+1)+ " es "+str(j)+", "])

print(Lista_Textos)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!